# Make UIButton "tappable" in tableView.backgroundView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

If you try to add a `UIButton` as a subview of the `backgroundView` of `tableView` you can realize that you can't tap on that button because the `backgroundView` is below the `UITableViewCell`s even when the table are empty.

Is there a way to make this button tappable?

Comment: Straightforward, NO.
if you want some functionality when there is some record in `tableView` make it part of `UITableViewCell`. And if there is no record, hide the tableView and that button will be tappable.

Comment: you cant not at least by sub viewing the button, but can you clear little more your scenario what do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: @iEngineer thanks. If I add the `UIButton` to `view` and hide `tableView` when it's empty then I can't use `UITableViewController` anymore. What a pity!

Comment: Do not use `UITableViewController`, use simple `UIViewController` and put `tableView` in it and call `UITableViewDelegate` methods.